# Disk size is show wrong value for Available

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, hard-disk, disk-usage, disk

I have two disks 4G each. I create raid with lvm. The size for Available is wrong or is my mistake.I don't understand why it show 6.9T and not 7.2T or 7.3T :/ thanks

**lsblk**

```
sda             8:0    0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─backup   253:0    0   7.3T  0 lvm   /media/backup
sdb             8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─backup   253:0    0   7.3T  0 lvm   /media/backup
```

**fdisk -l**

```
Size  Used Avail Use%
7.3T   93M  6.9T   1%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The available size is correct, by default ext4 reserves 5 % of the space for root (95 % of 7.3 TiB is 6.93 TiB). This isn't that important for other filesystems than `/` (where this prevents unprivileged processes from filling the filesystem), but it also helps with preventing fragmentation. You can change the reserve using `tune2fs -m 1 <device>` to set the reserve to 1 % (you can also change this when creating the filesystem using the same `-m 1` option with `mke2fs`).

From tune2fs manpage:

> -m reserved-blocks-percentage
>
> Set the percentage of the filesystem which may only be allocated by privileged  processes. Reserving  some  number  of filesystem blocks for use by privileged processes is done to avoid filesystem fragmentation, and to allow system daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue to function correctly after non-privileged processes are prevented from  writing  to  the filesystem.  Normally, the default percentage of reserved blocks is 5%.